# How to pass the information from function in the Express get API in MEAN Stack

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack

Here I have a function `hsResponse` which is as below and in the `console.log` I am getting the proper body response when I run this standalone, but now I wanted call inside the `app.get()` method and I wanted to put the response of `hsResponse` to the `app.get()` API response.

After running the API I wanted to get the body (the value which is printed in the `console.log`) of `hsResponse` instead of Root API.

How can I achieve this?

```
var hsResponse = request({
    proxy: proxyUrl,
    url: request_data.url,
    headers: request_data.headers,
    method: request_data.method,
    form: oauth.authorize(request_data)
}, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
});


app.get('', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Root API');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a function with a callback passed in parameter to handle the request result:

```
var hsResponse = function (done) {
    // done is a function, it will be called when the request finished 
    request({
        proxy: proxyUrl,
        url: request_data.url,
        headers: request_data.headers,
        method: request_data.method,
        form: oauth.authorize(request_data)
    }, function (error, response, body) {

        if (error) return done(error);

        done(null, body);
    });

}

app.get('', (req, res) => {

    hsResponse( function (err, body) {
        if (err) throw err;

        // get body here

        res.send('Root API');
    } );

});
```

**Edit** the code above buffers up the entire api response into memory (body) for every request before writing the result back to clients, and it could start eating a lot of memory if there were many requests at the same time. **Streams**, by using streams we could read one chunk at a time from the api response, store it into memory and send it back to the client:

```
app.get('', (req, res) => {

    request({
        proxy: proxyUrl,
        url: request_data.url,
        headers: request_data.headers,
        method: request_data.method,
        form: oauth.authorize(request_data)
    }).pipe(res);

});
```

Reference: [stream handbook](https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook)

Comment: Glad it helped, you could make it even more better by using streams, read this [article](https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook) for more info

Answer (score 1):

You can just put the code inside:

```
app.get('', (req, res) => {

    var hsResponse = request({
        proxy: proxyUrl,
        url: request_data.url,
        headers: request_data.headers,
        method: request_data.method,
        form: oauth.authorize(request_data)
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        res.send(body); //<-- send hsResponse response body back to your API consumer
    });

});
```